# Compiling multiple .as files using Maven

Tags: apache-flex, maven, actionscript, pom.xml, flexmojos

I am having issues getting maven to do a simple `clean install` I am getting the following error:

`Failed to execute goal org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:3.8:compile-swf (default-compile-swf) on project flex: Source file not expecified and no default found! -> [Help 1]`

I was following the tutorial on this site: [Adobe Developer Connection - Flex and Maven](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/flex-maven-flexmojos-pt1.html)

I have all of my .as files located in: `src/main/flex/` but the problem is that I don't have a Main class, these are all basically interfaces so I can't just choose one of them to be the source file.

I have Eclipse installed as well, and it is yelling at me for the plugin part of the POM, saying:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:
     3.8:compile-swf (execution: default-compile-swf, phase: compile)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.sonatype.flexmojos:flexmojos-maven-plugin:
     3.8:test-compile (execution: default-test-compile, phase: test-compile)
```

So I am not sure if this is related or not, but I have tried to copy/paste the code from the link above verbatim but I still get that error and the guy never mentions anything about it, so perhaps it's just a bug in the maven plugin in Eclipse.

Here is my POM.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>flex</artifactId>
    <name>flex</name>
    <packaging>swf</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>common</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.adobe.flex.framework</groupId>
            <artifactId>flex-framework</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.16995</version>
            <type>pom</type>            
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/flex</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
                <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                        <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                        <version>3.6.0.16995</version>
                        <type>pom</type>
                    </dependency>                   
                </dependencies>             
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I am open to ANY ideas on how to get this to compile these .as files. Thank you!

Edit: Okay I figured it out. I changed the packaging from swf to swc and it works. So very sad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted the package from `swf` to `swc` and it worked like a champ. Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you need the configuration tag so flexmojos knows where to start the build. (default application, or main class)

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.sonatype.flexmojos</groupId>
            <artifactId>flexmojos-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.adobe.flex</groupId>
                    <artifactId>compiler</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                           <sourceFile>Module.mxml</sourceFile>
                    </configuration>
                    <version>3.6.0.16995</version>
                    <type>pom</type>
                </dependency>                   
            </dependencies>             
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Unfortunately my project didn't have any .mxml files, it was just .as files. But I figured it out... Thank you for the reply!

Comment: yes, maven is a miracle when it works, and a curse when it doesnt :)